# Data will remain after the activity is destroyed in Android

Tags: android

After the User logged in and ticked the checkbox for "Keep me Logged in", the activity will proceed to another activity where it has many EditTexts. However, if the user accidentally close/shutdown the device, the data will be retrieved upon going back to that application since the user ticked the "Keep me Logged in". I used onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState but it doesn't help. Please help me with this.

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    final EditText txt_Fname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_Fname);
    final EditText txt_Mname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_Mname);
    final EditText txt_Lname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_Lname);
    final EditText txt_Suffix = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_Suffix);

    String Fname = txt_Fname.getText().toString();
    String Mname = txt_Mname.getText().toString();
    String Lname = txt_Lname.getText().toString();
    String Suffix = txt_Suffix.getText().toString();

    outState.putString("shared_fname", Fname);
    outState.putString("shared_mname", Mname);
    outState.putString("shared_lname", Lname);
    outState.putString("shared_suffix", Suffix);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    final EditText txt_Fname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_Fname);
    final EditText txt_Mname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_Mname);
    final EditText txt_Lname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_Lname);
    final EditText txt_Suffix = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_Suffix);

    txt_Fname.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("shared_fname"));
    txt_Mname.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("shared_mname"));
    txt_Lname.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("shared_lname"));
    txt_Suffix.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("shared_suffix"));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use SharedPreference to save data, when you switching between activities and shutting down the application. Below are example methods, you can call during onCreate() and onDestroy().

```
void saveText() {
    sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    Editor ed = sPref.edit();
    ed.putString(SAVED_TEXT, etText.getText().toString());
    ed.commit();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Text saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

  void loadText() {
    sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String savedText = sPref.getString(SAVED_TEXT, "");
    etText.setText(savedText);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Text loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
```

Comment: where should I called that methods?

Comment: what exactly is not working? Shared preference on Android works perfectly)

Comment: I can't retrieved the data that has been inputted on EditTexts by the user.

Comment: If you want to use common data for several activities use  getSharedPreferences